# Geoserver WMS raster problem

Tags: raster, geoserver, wms, orthophoto

I have the following problem:

[image]

The edge of the imagemosaic is not fit well, Im using geoserver imagemosaic tool to serving orthophotos through wms server. Is it a CRS, Bounding Box problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the imagemosaic setting (in the layer page), try setting "output transparent color" to black

Comment: How can I do it with a single GeoTiff? It has only input transparent color option.. @andrea-aime

Comment: Simple, you cannot, you have to use a mosaic (it can be used for a single file too, clumsy I agree, but it's probably the easiest solution).

Comment: thanks for this, it solved my problem which was having black spaces between the tiles instead of transparency

Answer (score 2):

Does the data get reprojected? Typically when I reproject raster to a different coordinate system I get black edges like that, because the raster file itself is rectangular, but the area covered by the reprojected data isn't. The black parts are areas of 'nodata'. If it's an issue of the look of the thing, perhaps you can make nodata transparent or white?

Comment: Thanks Mark, Everything fine, How can I rid of nodata? Is it settings in geoserver?